# Construct dataframe with weekly data from dataframe of Daily data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get weekly data from dataframe based on Dates column but facing issue is that my code is taking sunday as weekend date for each week that's not intended, because in dataframe there are some weeks set don't follow standard week schedule like Monday - Friday/Sunday, instead some weeks ends on Saturday or Thursday or Wednesday. and some week starts from Tuesday/Wednesday

**Output Expected**

1. new dataframe that have column Date and weekday, where Date is the last date of particular week and weekday will have name of day for that date eg: Friday/Thursday
2. Get cumulative high/Low for that week, Open value of the week that will be first value of the week and Close last value of that week.
3. Looking for some robust solution because my dataframe size is 600k+ records

**Dataframe**

| Table | Open | High | Low | Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Apr-2011 | 11800.00 | 11800.00 | 11602.00 | 11677.10 |
| 4-Apr-2011 | 11703.95 | 11919.00 | 11684.00 | 11884.95 |
| 5-Apr-2011 | 11900.00 | 11925.00 | 11728.00 | 11861.45 |
| 6-Apr-2011 | 11866.10 | 11897.95 | 11733.80 | 11785.05 |
| 7-Apr-2011 | 11772.95 | 11876.40 | 11695.05 | 11801.25 |
| 8-Apr-2011 | 11780.00 | 11889.90 | 11665.20 | 11711.60 |
| 11-Apr-2011 | 11610.00 | 11700.00 | 11590.05 | 11629.55 |
| 13-Apr-2011 | 11540.60 | 11918.00 | 11531.00 | 11903.10 |
| 15-Apr-2011 | 11900.00 | 11996.85 | 11740.20 | 11771.65 |
| 18-Apr-2011 | 11777.00 | 11941.90 | 11553.00 | 11575.10 |
| 19-Apr-2011 | 11565.00 | 11675.00 | 11512.05 | 11632.30 |
| 20-Apr-2011 | 11722.10 | 11860.00 | 11650.25 | 11843.05 |
| 21-Apr-2011 | 11898.00 | 11960.00 | 11863.55 | 11926.00 |
| 25-Apr-2011 | 11890.00 | 12025.00 | 11890.00 | 11921.70 |
| 26-Apr-2011 | 11919.95 | 11939.90 | 11723.00 | 11899.00 |
| 27-Apr-2011 | 11943.00 | 11965.00 | 11751.30 | 11804.75 |
| 28-Apr-2011 | 11860.00 | 11870.00 | 11650.00 | 11687.05 |
| 29-Apr-2011 | 11740.10 | 11774.85 | 11431.00 | 11511.75 |
| 30-Apr-2011 | 11588.80 | 11588.80 | 11229.00 | 11284.00 |

Code I tried:

```
temp_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp_df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
# set the date column as the index
temp_df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

# resample the data to weekly frequency and aggregate with OHLC method
weekly_data = temp_df.resample('W').agg({'High':'max', 'Low':'min', 'Open':'first', 'Close':'last'}).reset_index()
weekly_data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(weekly_data['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
weekly_data['Date'] = weekly_data['Date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

But this taking Sunday as week-end day, though data for High/low/Open/Close is correct only problem is with weekday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is only for `one year`. Then I can offer the following (if more than one year, then it will be necessary to `group additionally and by year`).

You can try to create a `'wk'` column that returns the week number of the year and `group` to `aggregate` by it.

And after the aggregation, rewrite the `'wk'` column as the day of the week (where `Monday = 0`). Or if you need a string day of the week, use `day_name()` instead of `dayofweek`.

```
import pandas as pd


df['Table'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Table'], format='%d-%b-%Y')
df['wk'] = df['Table'].dt.isocalendar().week

df_new = df.groupby('wk').aggregate({'Table' : ['max'], 'Open' : ['first'],
                                     'High' : ['max'], 'Low' : ['min'],
                                     'Close' : ['last']}).reset_index()


df_new.columns = df_new.columns.droplevel(1)
df_new['wk'] = df_new['Table'].dt.dayofweek

print(df_new)
```

Output

```
   wk      Table      Open      High       Low     Close
0   4 2011-04-01  11800.00  11800.00  11602.00  11677.10
1   4 2011-04-08  11703.95  11925.00  11665.20  11711.60
2   4 2011-04-15  11610.00  11996.85  11531.00  11771.65
3   3 2011-04-21  11777.00  11960.00  11512.05  11926.00
4   5 2011-04-30  11890.00  12025.00  11229.00  11284.00
```

If there is more than one year in the data, then see the following code. Here two columns are created at once 'wk'(week number of the year), 'ye'(year).

```
df_new = df.assign(wk=df['Table'].dt.isocalendar().week, ye=df['Table'].dt.year).groupby(['wk', 'ye'])\
    .aggregate({'Table': ['max'], 'Open': ['first'],'High': ['max'], 'Low': ['min'],
                'Close': ['last']}).reset_index()

df_new.columns = df_new.columns.droplevel(1)
df_new = df_new.sort_values(by=['Table']).drop(columns=['ye']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Update 22.04.2022**

In the `bbb` list, I found the indexes where the week begins last year. I found these lines in the loop and reset the year in the `'ye'` column to the next one (since 2017, only two iterations 2018-2019 and 2019-2020 used SPY index quotes with yfinance).

```
df = df.assign(wk=df['Table'].dt.isocalendar().week, ye=df['Table'].dt.year)


bbb = df[(df['wk'] < df['wk'].shift()) & (df['ye'] == df['ye'].shift())].index

for i in bbb:
    aaa = df[(df.index >= i) & (df['ye'] == df.loc[i, 'ye'])].index
    df.loc[aaa, 'ye'] = df.loc[df['ye'] > df.loc[i, 'ye'], 'ye'].values[0]

df_new = df.groupby(['wk', 'ye'])\
    .aggregate({'Table': ['max'], 'Open': ['first'],'High': ['max'], 'Low': ['min'],
                'Close': ['last']}).reset_index()

df_new.columns = df_new.columns.droplevel(1)
df_new = df_new.sort_values(by=['Table']).drop(columns=['wk','ye']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I tried this code with my final data which contains multiple years from 2016 to 2023, it works fine but from 31-Dec-2018 it gives wrong result, because it treat as 31-Dec-2018 as separate week but what it should do is it should consider 31 as part of 4 - jan- 2019 week. ANy idea on how to resolve this.

Comment: See the update, it reinstalled the lines with the year for the next year, where there is an intersection.